# Schematic Review Request: Controller Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematic

I am a ME, not an EE, so bear with my ignorance please.  My schematic probably will make that clear, ha.

I am designing a circuit which interfaces a 12V vehicle system with GPIO on two microcontrollers. One controls logic and states, the other LED routines. Components are selected to be workable by hand (mostly DIP). All user inputs are via BLE, so this is just interface with the vehicle and LEDs.

There are:

- 2x Microcontrollers- Seeeed XIAO regular and BLE versions
- 1x 12V input (Active signal), optocoupled to GPIO 3.3V
- 1x Ground input (EXTFS Signal), optocoupled to GPIO 3.3V
- 2x SPDT relays 5V coils 80 mA,  3.3V GPIO optocoupled to 5V mosfet drivers with LED indicators
- 1x 3.3V to 5V logic shifter/LED driver and LED output circuit
- 1x I2C FRAM module
- 2x Isolated DC/DC power supply units 9-36V in, 5V out with protection circuitry.
- 2x analog sensor inputs to one microcontroller
- A slew of screw terminals for inputs to the routine and future expansion of unused pins on the second MC.

I would humbly request a review of my schematic design here for any obvious electrical mishaps if anyone has the time and interest... capacitor and resistor size review, and proper design of my relay isolation circuits and optocoupled input circuits in particular.

All components are properly labeled with part numbers as designed currently.

[image: PCB R5]

Comment: Missing decoupling capacitors on every IC, routed ground and 5V instead of a simple symbol.

Comment: thanks. recommend 0.1uF ceramics across 5V and G on the FRAM, MC1 and MC2 power terminals? or 1uF?                                                              thank you, yes i have a friend i intend to help me reroute more cleanly ASAP with physical layout in mind, just checking the rest first. this is my first usage of KiCAD so i haven't made it to the plane layouts just yet.                                   please let me know if i have misinterpreted anything in your suggestions. thanks!

Comment: Sorry, routed may not have been the right word. Don’t draw long lines all over the schematic for repeated signals like GND and Vcc, use symbols. KiCad have standard symbols available. Use 0.1 uF unless the datasheet says otherwise.

Comment: copy that and thank you very much.

Comment: schematic updated to R01 with repeated power and grounds as symbols and 0.1uF ceramics on IC power inputs. thanks

Comment: Much better. Approaching nit-picking levels here. Some of your symbols have Vcc and GND swapped, which prevents really clean looking schematics where all positive voltages point up, ground and negative point down. This will not affect your netlist or function of the schematic in any way, just improve human readability.

Comment: I will update! Thank you, nitpicking is gladly and humbly accepted!

Comment: In your configuration, your OPTO_2 and OPTO_3 optocouplers are useless. It's better to drive the mosfets directly.

Comment: the idea was to optocouple GPIO from the 5v, and drive the mosfet with 5V.  i could lose OPTO_1 and OPTO_2 in favor of a mosfet that can be driven within the current requirements of the GPIO on 3.3V, yes? do you by chance have a recommendation for such a mosfet part number? thanks!

Comment: sorry, OPTO_2 and OPTO_3 (correction to above)

Comment: If i do not change it from current, i think i should be feeding +5VP rather than +5VL into that circuit to isolate it properly also, yes?  thanks!

Comment: You can use the existing opto but you need to add a pull down resistor form the emitter to ground.

Comment: 10K OHM to ground  between emitter and 1K OHM resistors on each, and leave the mosfets feeding +5VP in instead? thanks!

Comment: @ElChavo, In general, if the GNDs before and after the optocouplers are the same, the optocouplers are useless and can be replaced by a transistor. The 2N7000 or 7002 can be driven by the microcontroller's +5V, as the VGS(th) is 3V max. If you remove the optocouplers, place a pull-down resistor before R10 and R9 to help discharge the MOSFET gate. Make sure that the relay current does not overheat the MOSFET (Relay current * RDSon).

Comment: thank you @Vincent, this microcontroller GPIO is 3.3V, 5V is only a power leg. in this case i cannot use 2N7000 can I? with grounds being shared, i suppose it doesnt matter which +5V i use at that circuit, P or L also

Comment: pulldowns added

Comment: @ElChavo, You're right, prefer the 2N7002 because the VGS(th)max is 2.5V at 25°C. Don't forget that relays will cause inrush currents on the 5V. It's often handy to have a dedicated 5V for relays.

Comment: is it enough to have them use the larger power supply +5VP with a shared circuit ground? that supply otherwise only powers the LED strip.      the max GPIO output current is 150 mA on 3.3V GPIO, i think this is insufficient to drive the gate on the 2N7002 yes? this is why i used an optocoupler to mosfet currently

Comment: +5VP is now fed into the relay circuit instead, with returning via GND2 close to the larger power supply, with a diode to isolate just that +5VP and GND2 circuit from the GND1 and +5VP circuit, which interfaces the LEDs with the MC. I think this accomplishes a protection loop for the relays, and keeping the optocouplers allows the use of 2N7000 as is with 3.3V GPIO- as is does this look OK?